# Can I specify nargout as part of a MATLAB function call?

Tags: matlab, indexing

The problem:

I want to index into the result of a function call that returns a variable number of output arguments without storing the result in a temporary.

```
getel = @(x,i) x(i); #% simple anonymous function to index into a vector
x = zeros(2,2,2);
row = getel(ind2sub(size(x), 8), 1) #% desired: 2 (row 2)
#% actual: 8 (linear index)-because ind2sub is returning 1 value only
[row col dep]=ind2sub(size(x),8) #% row=2, ind2sub returning 3 values
```

Example usage:

```
x(1).val1 = [1 2 3];
x(1).val2 = [2 1 2];
x(2).val1 = [2 1 2];
x(2).val2 = [1 0 0];

#% The normal way I would do this, with a temporary variable
[~,ind] = min(x(1).val2); #% ind=2
v(1) = x(1).val1(ind);
[~,ind] = min(x(2).val2); #% ind=2
v(2) = x(2).val1(ind);

#% I'd like to be able to do this with arrayfun:
v = arrayfun(@(s) s.val1(min(s.val2), x);
                  -------^ returns value of minimum, not index
```

The above arrayfun doesn't work - the form of min that is called returns one output: the minimum value.  To make it work right, one option would be the following hypothetical function call:

```
v = arrayfun(@(s) s.val1(getoutputnum(2, 2, @min, s.val2)), x);
   hypothetical function -----------^ ^  ^  ^-func  ^--func args
      which form (nargout) of func ---|  |- which arg to return
```

I realize that for the above scenario, I could use

```
s.val1(find(s.val2==min(s.val2),1,'first'))
```

or other tricks, but that isn't possible in all cases.

In the case of `ind2sub`, I may want to know the index into a particular dimension (columns, say) - but the 1-output form of the function returns only a linear index value - the n-dimensional form needs to be called, even if the value of dimension 1 is what I care about.

Note: I realize that writing a function file would make this trivial: use `~` and the `[out] = func(in)` form.  However, when writing scripts or just on the command line, it would be nice to be able to do this all within anonymous functions.  I also realize that there are undoubtedly other ways to get around the problem; I would just like to know if it is possible to specify which form of a function to call, and perhaps which output number to be returned, without using the `out=func(in)` syntax, thus allowing functions to be nested much more nicely.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your question right. Are you trying to have several output variables for an anonymous function?

Comment: @EitanT I edited the question; hopefully it is more clear. I'm finding it tricky to describe the problem fully but still concisely. To answer your question directly, I know how to return multiple args from an anonymous function, so that isn't the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

In its own file:

```
function idx=mymin(x)
  [~,idx] = min(x);
```

In your code:

```
v = arrayfun(@(s) s.val1(mymin(s.val2), x);
```

Might have syntax errors; I don't have MATLAB on the computer I'm writing this on. The idea is there though: just wrap MATLAB's `min` and capture the second argument, which is the logical indexing for the position of the minimum value in `x`.

Comment: As I mentioned at the end of the question (in the Note section), this would certainly work, but I'd prefer to not need to create files for things like this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can get ind2sub() to return the variable number of args like this:

```
x = zeros(2,2,2);
c = cell(ndims(x),1);
[c{:}] = ind2sub(size(x), 8);
```

The c cell array will now have the 3D indices c = {2;2;2}.

```
[c{:}] = ind2sub(size(x), 2);
```

would produce c = {2;1;1}.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: While this does let you call ind2sub without knowing ahead of time how many dimensions there are, it isn't usable inside an single expression - so it can't be used in an anonymous function within arrayfun, for example.